# What can I do about exhausted memory on Wordpress while developing via a local Ubuntu server?

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu

Some short facts first:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on VirtualBox with 4096M ram.
- PHP 7.0.22
- Wordpress 4.9.2.
- macOS 10.13.2
- Using a shared folder to access my websites via localaddress.vm/[websitename]

I have set up a local Ubuntu server via VirtualBox to not having to use MAMP anymore. I develop Wordpress websites.
Frontend of the Wordpress website is all good. /wp-admin is also playing nice but after successfully logging in, I am not getting redirected to the Dashboard. Instead I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to 
allocate 262144 bytes) in /media/sf_sharedwww/thermoshield/wp-
includes/functions.php on line 1872

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to 
allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
```

Tried solutions:

- Upping the RAM on my VirtualBox
- Upping the memory_limit for WP via `wp-config.php`
- Upping the memory_limit via the `php.ini` file.
- Basically the first page of Google results

Please help, I cannot continue development if I can't access the back-end of Wordpress.

Comment: Which php.ini file have you altered previously?

Comment: By modifying the wp-config.php have you increased the memory like this : `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );`  ???

Comment: Have you checked what is happening when you are logging in? So there is not an infinity loop or something like that?

Comment: DO NOT increase memory limit. You should look where the memory is leaking, either an infinite loop, or you're getting data from the database you don't need or you're creating unnecessary data, either way, optimize your code. 
Or if it's not your code, check which plugin is making that problem.

Comment: @JezEmery The one on the Ubuntu server.

Comment: @AlcaeusD Yes, I did.

Comment: @zarex360 No not yet. But when I load the website via MAMP, it doesn't have any issues. Therefore I am thinking it's a problem with the VirtualBox.

Comment: @Imaginaroom Good reply, thank you. Will definitely check this out closer in the code. Thing is: we are just making a new theme for this client, he previously used Enfold and installed LOTS of plugins but he uses them. So I can't just go around disabling plugins.